# Detect Collision in Animation Event

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have animation Clip for swinging sword. At a specific frame, I added Event. I want when player swing sword, in that case only the enemy could die.

So I added the following `OnTriggerEnter` Code

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
{
        hit = true;
        if (hit)
        {
            if (col.GetComponent<Collider>().tag == "enemy")
            {
                Destroy(col.gameObject);
            }
        }
}
```

When I try to add function OnTriggerEnter (in animation Clip) as animation Event, it is asking me to pass Collider parameter, Which i am not able to add.

[Here is the screen shot of Add Event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osvJV.jpg)

Please help me , how can I add event with collider ( as parameter ) at a specific frame.. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Collision` and `Trigger` events are called on their own on every frame.

Call another public method from animation event for your task and put necessary `Boolean` or `Enum` there to control collision, trigger after swinging the sword.

```
public void SwingingSword()
{
 isSwingingSword = true; // make it false when not swinging the sword.
}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
{
  hit = true; // not sure what it's job here

  if (isSwingingSword && hit)
  {
   if (col.GetComponent<Collider>().tag == "enemy")
   {
    Destroy(col.gameObject);
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice.. Thanks..for your help :-)